# Autocompete search as the value of inputs changes

Tags: jquery, forms, search, input

I have a search form like  -

[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7dKk.png)

What i am trying to do is to get the result with jquery and php as user changes the value of any of the form elements but i am only able to do when all of them are treat as single and no other option is there. But i want to trigger the even every time when any form value changes.

```
google.load("jquery", "1.3.1");
google.setOnLoadCallback(function()
{
    // Safely inject CSS3 and give the search results a shadow
    var cssObj = { 'box-shadow' : '#888 5px 10px 10px', // Added when CSS3 is standard
        '-webkit-box-shadow' : '#888 5px 10px 10px', // Safari
        '-moz-box-shadow' : '#888 5px 10px 10px'}; // Firefox 3.5+
    $("#suggestions").css(cssObj);

    // Fade out the suggestions box when not active
     /*$("input").blur(function(){
        $('#suggestions').fadeOut();
     });*/
});

function lookup(inputString) {
    if(inputString.length == 0) {
        $('#suggestions').fadeOut(); // Hide the suggestions box
    } else {
        $.post("regularsearch.php", {queryString: ""+inputString+""}, function(data) { // Do an AJAX call
            $('#suggestions').fadeIn(); // Show the suggestions box
            $('#suggestions').html(data); // Fill the suggestions box
        });
    }
}
```

Above is the jquery for one of my elements search. How to do search for all at once?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a jquery plugin that I wrote that might help you figure it out. It uses ajax to retrieve data from server as the user types.

http://jsfiddle.net/alforno/g4stL/

Comment: what you have shown is what i got no addition that what i ask for

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly then you will need a function defined that gets the value of all search inputs and fires the search, and then assign the function as an event handler for each input control's value change event.

Comment: if you have seen the image then you know that there are many inputs like of radio button and select and text types, so i want that if user changes the value of any that value get trigger and retrieved data from the mysql db without refreshing the page.